# Calculation One-sided limit

Tags: limits

i can solve limits :$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) $

i can not solve limits: $\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x) $ and $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x) $

How can they be solved ?

How do I convert?$\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x) =\lim_{x\to a} g(x) $

How do I convert?$\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x) =\lim_{x\to a} g(x) $

What  theorem ?

such as :

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} |x|=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} |x|=\lim_{x\to 0}h(x)$$

Comment: Generally, if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists, then$$\lim_{x\to a}f=\lim_{x\to a^-}f=\lim_{x\to a^+}f$$For when $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ doesn't exist, you usually will start out with piecewise functions, so consider each piece based on if its on the left or right sides of the limit point.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment above pointed out we have the following theorem:

> For a function $f:A \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and a $x_0$ an [accumulation point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AccumulationPoint.html) of $A$ we say that the limit of $f$ when the function approach to $x_0$ and we wright  $$\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) = L$$ *if, and only if it is also true that*
>   $$\lim_{x \to x_0^{+}}f(x) = L = \lim_{x \to x_0^{-}}f(x)$$

So, as you pointed out that it is possible to solve

$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$$

Then you'll have that this limit is equal to the one-sided limits. This is because of the theorem above. For the example that you pointed out the right-hand side limit equals the left-hand side (both zero) and the limit itself is zero.

The proof of the theorem above follows directly from the definition of one-sided limits, because the definition is completely equal of the definition of limit just with the difference of restricting the $\delta$-interval for just the right or left side of the accumulation point. See [this](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~reinholz/ed/08fa_m160/lectures/one-sided_limits.pdf) for some examples and the definitions, you can see that difference in the delta range and how this is related to the limit definition.